# Using a double LEFT JOIN to find entries where an object has no entries in a particular state

Tags: sql, join

I have a triple of tables: Members, Tickets, Events

Members are linked to events through a ticket. So a member has many tickets each of which has an event.

**I want to find all members who do not have any tickets to an event that is finished.**

The following solution works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT tickets.member_id, tickets.id, events.state
  FROM tickets INNER JOIN events ON events.id = tickets.event_id
  WHERE events.state = 'finished'
 ) AS tickets
ON tickets.member_id = members.id WHERE (tickets.id is NULL)
```

However, for performance reasons (I need to chain this select with other queries) I need to able to write this not as a nested query but as a double LEFT JOIN on members, tickets, and events. I've spent a while trying to do this, and this is the closest I can come to that, but it's not quite right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "members"."id") FROM "members" 
LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.member_id = members.id 
LEFT JOIN events ON tickets.event_id = events.id AND events.state = 'finished'
WHERE (events.id is NULL)
```

This seems like a very common question one might want to ask on a SQL database, so I'm guessing there must be a good way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: What's not quite right about it?  You don't need the first `DISTINCT`, but what error/incorrect result are you getting?

Comment: Subtlety question here: Do you want members who have no tickets *at all* to be included in the result? Or only members who have tickets to *something* - just so long as that *something* isn't "finished"?

Comment: Members who don't have any tickets should be included in the result. @DavidW

Comment: Sample data and desired output makes such a difference on questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the tickets and events are a one-to-one map and there is no reason to do a double LEFT JOIN. You could just to an INNER JOIN between `tickets` and `events`, and then a LEFT JOIN from `members` and the resulting set between tickets and events.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "members"."id") 
  FROM "members" 
       LEFT JOIN tickets 
            INNER JOIN events 
               ON tickets.event_id = events.id AND events.state = 'finished'
         ON tickets.member_id = members.id 
 WHERE (events.id is NULL)
```